# JDBC command to insert/delete/update multiple records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, jdbc

suppose I have a table that has the following keys:

```
1
2
3
```

and then I get a new request (JSON list) to update that table with:

```
2
4
```

The user wants me to delete 1 and 3.  Keep (possibly update) 2 and add 4.  I can write a bunch of code t loop and perform this operation but is there some automated JDBC command that will perform the merge for me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to delete all previous rows and insert new rows.
you just need to write 2 queries.
1) delete all previous rows
2) Insert new rows

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ORM library like [sormula](http://www.sormula.org) that would do all of the work for you with [deleteAll](http://www.sormula.org/javadoc/org/sormula/Table.html#deleteAll%28%29) and [insertAll](http://www.sormula.org/javadoc/org/sormula/Table.html#insertAll%28java.util.Collection%29) methods.

Include deletes and inserts within a transaction if more than one thread may perform this at the same time.

If you wanted the "union" of old and new, [sormula](http://www.sormula.org) has [save](http://www.sormula.org/javadoc/org/sormula/Table.html#deleteAll%28%29) and [saveAll](http://www.sormula.org/javadoc/org/sormula/Table.html#insertAll%28java.util.Collection%29) methods.